# Forecasting data of export Wh

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to R. I am analyzing export Wh, data for my project. May I know how should I apply ARIMA forecasting method to this export Wh data analysing ?

In the original csv file, there are 1,584,823 total records, with 157 meters.
Recorded from 1-Oct-2015 00:00:10-05 to 31-Mar-2016 23:59:58

In the csv file, there are three columns: local minutes, dataID, meter_value.

Local minutes is formatted with “yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss-UTC
time offset”.
dataID represents the ID number for each 157 meter,
meter_value represents the export Wh

Quick view of original csv file, as below:

```
localminute,dataid,meter_value
2015-10-01 00:00:10-05,739,88858
2015-10-01 00:00:13-05,8890,197164
2015-10-01 00:00:20-05,6910,179118
2015-10-01 00:00:22-05,3635,151318
2015-10-01 00:00:22-05,1507,390354
2015-10-01 00:00:29-05,5810,97506
2015-10-01 00:01:18-05,6910,179118
```

I tried using ARIMA method for forecasting meter value for next 6 months., but i could not get the forecast meter value, only I got next 10 local minutes. At first, I would like to get meter value to be foretasted for 24 hours,

my code as below:
I appreciate your help.

```
> library(readxl) library(forecast)   library(ggplot2)  
> library(tidyverse)  library(lubridate) # easier to work with dates and
> times in R library(data.table) 
> 
> #---------Data importing to R(Read csv file to R) -------------------- 
sensor_data <- data.table::fread("org_data.csv")  

    > #---------Data Processing: Converting variables --------------------  
   sensor_data <- sensor_data %>% mutate(localminute
    > =lubridate::as_datetime(localminute),dataid=factor(dataid)) 
   # convert dataid (integer type) to factor type # convert localminute to datetime
    > (fread imports it as character)
    > 
    > str(sensor_data)  #sensor_data is original data set 
    > # str() function- to look at internal representation of numbers
    > # localminute: POSIXct, format: "2015-10-01 05:00:10" ...
    > # dataid     : Factor w/ 157 levels "35","44"
    > # meter_value: int  88858, 197164 179118, .....
    > 
    > sensor_dataTS = ts(sensor_data$localminute)
> #convert the POSIXct format to time series,
> 
> meterValueTS = ts(sensor_data$meter_value)
    > 
    > Alldata <- data.frame(sensor_dataTS,sensor_data$dataid,meterValueTS)
```

---

I tried without adding frequency interval when converting meter_value into time series meter_value. 
`meterValueTS = ts(sensor_data$meter_value) 
 arima_fit=auto.arima(Alldata$meterValueTS)
arima_forecast = forecast(arima_fit, h = 10)
arima_forecast
PPoint Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
1584824       202242.8  15172.63 389313.0  -83856.34 488342.0
1584825       163675.2 -25595.56 352946.0 -125789.46 453139.9
1584826       157226.5 -35231.01 349684.1 -137111.87 451564.9
1584827       156870.7 -40095.10 353836.6 -144362.52 458104.0
1584828       160228.8 -42799.01 363256.7 -150275.46 470733.2
1584829       159133.8 -51824.79 370092.3 -163499.50 481767.0
1584830       166694.8 -54544.42 387934.1 -171661.41 505051.1
1584831       160538.4 -65439.76 386516.5 -185065.35 506142.1
1584832       160058.2 -71226.73 391343.1 -193661.57 513777.9
1584833       160595.1 -76425.99 397616.2 -201897.36 523087.5`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the frequency of the time series in the `ts` function. If meters are read multiple times per day and you want minutes and days then you can specify multiple seasonal frequencies. If you only want days then you may want to re-format that local_minutes column to just date first.

Comment: Hi Chris, May I know how should I do it?

Comment: Try for yourself first, this is a good article: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/

Comment: does it necessary to do timeseries for both local_minute and meter_value variable ? or only have to do time series for meter_value for forecasting 24hours export Wh for 157 meters (dataID)

Comment: ahh so there is another problem in your code I didn't notice the first time. The `ts` object should be built on the meter value, not the time. The seasonal frequency argument should describe your date/time field. So you only create `ts` for the meter_value.

Comment: hi chris, the original "local minute" is in char type, hence i converted to `mutate(localminute =lubridate::as_datetime(localminute)` so that I could plot all the meterID before forecasting. 
Shall i continue use local_minute as POSIXct, format: "2015-10-01 05:00:10 or should convert back to char format "2015-10-01 00:01:34-05"

Comment: strictly referring to the `ts` object it should not matter-- because you're not going to reference your datetime.

Comment: I added the interval in meter_value time series, but the output of date is weird `meterValueTS = ts(sensor_data$meter_value,start= c(2015,10,1), end = c(2016,5,30), frequency = 86400)
arima_fit=auto.arima(meterValueTS)
arima_forecast = forecast(arima_fit, h = 20)
 Point Forecast       Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95
2016.000058       186516.4   -3608.859 376641.7 -104255.09 477287.9
2016.000069       202744.3   10310.673 395177.9  -91557.52 497046.1
2016.000081       171042.8  -24601.370 366686.9 -128169.13 470254.7
2016.000093       169833.4  -30416.936 370083.8 -136423.08 476089.9'

Comment: Using 86400 implies you have an observation every second, I don’t believe that’s the case. How frequent are the observations and what seasonality do you think will be present?

Comment: Hi chris, i realized that the data I am analyzing is irregular time series, hence I will use zoo function to fill up some missing data of existing, before I predict data for next 24hours.

Answer (score 0):

how should I get the predicted result according to the original data set format 
Quick view of original csv file, as below:
I tried to use ARIMA method to forecast, but could not get the desired output. As there are 157 meters,I expect to get every minutes has 157 meter_values for all meters(dataID)

```
localminute,dataid,meter_value
2016-04-01 05:00:00-05,739,xxxxx
```